# Why is there a hole in my slab?

Tags: concrete, foundation, slab

We had a leaky pipe burst over the weekend. It seems that it had been leaking (slowly) for some time, so there's some water damage to the wall where it was located. In order to clean it up, I removed a cabinet on the opposite side of the wall from where we repaired the leak and found an unusual hole in the slab.

[image: Hole in the Foundation]

This cabinet is in a ground-floor powder room. The leak was in one of the exposed pipes in the wall on the left. The pipes running horizontally along the back wall are the result of a reroute of hot and cold lines due to two different leaks under the slab.

Some background: the house is in Southern California, constructed in the early 2000s.

**The thing I'm curious about is why there's a hole in the slab, exposing the dirt below?** My hypothesis is that the original owner had the option, while the house was under construction, to have a shower installed here. If that's correct, then I would expect to find a drain underneath that dirt.

**If we wished to cover that dirt, what would be the best way to go about it?** Can we did out some of that dirt, mix some concrete, and fill it?

Comment: Looks like it was intended to be a sump with a pump to remove ground water but was not finished.

Comment: @blacksmith37 Thanks for the suggestion, I didn't think of that. This is a hole in a concrete slab foundation in part of the country which is generally quite dry, so there's no basement and no tendency to flood or for water to pool anywhere - maybe not a sump? (Although I don't know much about sumps, so maybe it is needed here?)

Comment: To evaluate , you could dig down a couple feet with a post-hole digger and see if water collects.